# How to find objects by specifying the range of property value?

Tags: matlab, sorting, oop, object, properties

In Matlab I have defined a class and created a bunch of objects, how can I select a subset of all the objects by specifying a range for certain property?

For example, if I have a `person` class with properties `name` (char) and `height` (double), how can I find all the `person` with `height` between x and y?

In this [example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/finding-objects-having-specific-settings.html), it uses `findobj` to find object with `char` properties matches the *exact* value, like

```
NW = findobj(PB,'Name','Nancy Wong');
```

but how can I do that for numerical values and a range?

Answer (score 2):

You can manually create a logical vector acccording to the desired condition, and use to select the objects:

```
h = [PB.height]; % collect all height values in a vector
ind = (x<=h) & (h<=y); % logical index of values in the desired range
NW = PB(ind); % apply that index to select objects
```